# change scatterplot points and coloring

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have below simple scatterplot generated with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Now I want to change scatterplot of this such that each point has a different according to the value of its “Tree” variable and change the default ggplot2 coloring behavior, use more sharp colors like red, blue, orange, green, etc.

Comment: `geom_point(color = factor(Tree))`.  Take a look at the default colors it assigns - if you don't like them, check out the `RColorBrewer` package

Comment: I need to change scatterplot of this such that each point has a different according to the value of its “Tree” variable

Answer (score 1):

You can also take another variable in the dataset and use it as a "color" (totally not intuitive, but it works). I do like how this automatically creates the legend though.

```
ggplot(Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference, color=Tree)) + geom_point()
```

[image]